# Cannot change colour of DataGridView or set to ReadOnly

Tags: c#, datagridview, m

I have a datagridview where i need to disable rows where the checkbox value on that row isn't checked, here's the code:

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in catView.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString() != "true")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    row.Cells[i].Style.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                    row.Cells[i].ReadOnly = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Problem is that this doesn't set the colour or disable the checkbox, what am i getting wrong?

Thanks.

More info:

cells[1] is the checkbox column.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i == row.Cells.Count; i++)` what the heck is this - body most probably never execute

Comment: Loops over all cells on the row and sets thier ForeColor and ReadOnly values, at least that's what is should do.

Comment: Thanks, edited the loop but the issue still stands that even if the loop is referencing each cell those cells do not have thier values for ForeColor and ReadOnly set.

Comment: The code works fine but your condition does not. `Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[1].Value)` seems to be always true..? Maybe `Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[1].FormattedValue)` works better?

Comment: !Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[1].Value) works just fine here. But yes it might always be true, i'll try your suggestion but still the main issue stands.

Comment: `row.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString() != "true"` seems to work better, but I found that the checkbox cell never looks disabled, although it is..

Comment: Changed the question to reflect that, thanks. The issue is still in the loop though, it does go over each cell but the values are never set :(

Comment: That is weird. It works here, so there must be something else going on in your code..

Comment: Thanks for checking, the datagridview is populated via a datatable which is itself manually populated with data from a list of objects. I think the issue here will be with something in the visual studio designer code, I'll check that at a more reasonable hour :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `for` expression with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was an embaressing error but still the issue stands with the corrected loop, the vales for each cell are not set, I'm really not sure why.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in your loop to see if the lines that set the color and readonly are being hit?

Comment: No chance to debug here as there are complex dependancies for the application which cant be accessed when it's run directly from Visual Studio. I've added debug output to the loop though and it shows that the cells are definitly being looped over.

Answer (score 0):

You must dimension a new DataGridViewRow and set it.
In VB.NET I would do:

```
 dim MyLine as new DataGridViewRow
 with MyLine
      .Cells[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
      .Cells[i].ReadOnly = true;
 end with
```

Try it.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find a way to directly update the datagrid if its source was a datagrid, the code works fine after manually creating the columns and manually adding the rows to the datagrid.

I imagine those that are using a datatable to populate the datagrid will need to update the cells by using a format change event handler which commits the changes while the datagrid is being drawn.